# Wrapped lambda expressions

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda

Here's a lamba wrapper expression defined:

```
function <int(double)> f = 
     [](double x) -> int{ return static_cast <int> (x*x); };
```

It is used like this:

```
f(someintvalue);
```

What is the difference between normal functions and wrapped lambdas?

Comment: "defined in the STL"? How so?

Comment: "it"? What is "it"? What kind of part? Where did you see this code "in" the STL? The STL and the C++ Standard Library are both APIs of sorts; AFAIK neither of them give any implementation details such as lines of code like this.

Comment: oh, i just read about lambda expressions in the chapter about STL (Ivor Horton's book), so i thought it could be a part of STL, my mistake!

Comment: At times, it appears like any C++ that's not similar to Java must then be STL :(

Comment: Sounds like Ivor Horton is grossly misusing the term "STL". That's a shame. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> question is - what is the difference between normal function and wrapped lambda?

Normal function is a normal function and what you call "wrapped lambda" is actually a function object.

By the way, why use `std::function`? You could simply write this:

```
auto f = [](double x) { return static_cast <int> (x*x); };

//call
int result = f(100.0);
```

Also, I omitted the return type, as it is implicitly known to the compiler from the return expression. No need to write `-> int` in the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas can capture surrounding scope ([=] or [&]) resulting in anonymous structs that contain a member function.

Certain tasks, like accessing lambda (types) across Translation Units, or taking standard pointer-to-memberfunction addresses from lambdas may prove hard/useless because the actual type of the automatically generated 'anonymous' type cannot be known (and is in fact implementation defined).

`std::function<>` was designed to alleviate exactly *that* problem: being able to bind a function pointer (semantically) to a lambda (or indeed, whatever [*callable object*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Technical_Report_1#Polymorphic_function_wrapper))

---

> <sup>1</sup>: in fact the type can have external linkage, but you cannot *portably* refer to that from another translation unit because the actual type is implementation defined (and need not even be expressible in C++ code; within the original TU you'd be able to use `decltype` to get the *magic type*. Thanks, Luc for the good precisions about this)

Comment: Mmm... because lambdas are expressions they need not mention the linkage. I meant that you can not 'extern' a lambda, and as such you cannot use a lambda from another compilation unit directly (you can using a std::function<> intermediate). I'd actually need to check whether specific implementation would allow this anyway

Comment: @Luc: good catch. I think you could use that to 'prove' that the compiler-generated lambda class has external linkage! But you can still not access that type from another compilation unit since you cannot use `decltype` on the expression/variable. So _in effect_ you cannot share the type across compilation units. Does that make sense to you?